# How to rebuild widget tree, swapping the wrapper of a route path

Tags: flutter, auto-route

I am building a responsive app, using auto_route.

The application is a simple master/detail view. My requirement is that when in desktop mode, the master (list) will be displayed on the left, and the detail on the right, in a "split screen" style.

When in mobile mode, the application will display the master and list as sequential views, pushed and popped onto a navigator (i.e, on screen one at a time).

I achieve this with the folowing:
When in "desktop" mode, it will wrap the route with a "split screen" page. The split screen page has the list hard coded, and a child AutoRouter on the right.

When in "mobile" mode, it will wrap the route with a "stack screen" page. The stack screen is just a simple stack.

Now, I need to somehow restore the state between mobile and desktop modes, such that the path is retained.

i.e,
if in Desktop mode, and your path is /detail/:5, you will see the split screen, list on the left, detail "5" on the right.
Then you resize into mobile mode (this would happen when rotating a tablet for example) - your path remains the same, so the application switches you to the stack view, and restores a backstack with the "master list", and the "detail 5" pushed on top.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of AutoRoute has kindly offered a clean implementation which I have moved ahead with, and verified it works.
(Thank you Milad)

Details and a short demo video are here:
https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/discussions/1667

For the sake of SO history, here's a copy of the code

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'demo_router.gr.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  final router = DemoRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router.config(),
    );
  }
}

@AutoRouterConfig()
class DemoRouter extends $DemoRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(
          page: MasterRoute.page,
          initial: true,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(page: DetailsRoute.page, path: 'details'),
            AutoRoute(page: SubDetailsRoute.page, path: 'sub-details'),
          ],
        ),
      ];
}

@RoutePage()
class MasterScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MasterScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
    final splitMode = screenWidth > 600;
    final splitPosition = splitMode ? screenWidth / 2 : 0.0;
    return AutoRouter(
      builder: (context, subRouterWidget) {
        final subRouter = context.router;
        // in split mode we show the back button only if the sub router can pop (entries.length > 1)
        final showBackButton = splitMode ? subRouter.canPop() : subRouter.hasEntries;
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            /// we use router.popForced to always pop even if we have one entry in the stack
            leading: showBackButton ? BackButton(onPressed: subRouter.popForced) : null,
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned.fill(
                right: splitPosition,
                child: MasterScreenContent(),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(
                left: splitPosition,
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  transitionBuilder: (child, animation) {
                    /// mimic route transition
                    return SlideTransition(
                      position: Tween<Offset>(
                        begin: Offset(1, 0),
                        end: Offset.zero,
                      ).animate(animation),
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                  child: subRouter.hasEntries ? subRouterWidget : SizedBox(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MasterScreenContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const MasterScreenContent({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ColoredBox(
      color: Colors.grey.shade300,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Show details'),
            onPressed: () {
              context.navigateTo(DetailsRoute());
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


@RoutePage()
class DetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DetailsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DetailsScreen> createState() => _DetailsScreenState();
}

class _DetailsScreenState extends State<DetailsScreen> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text('Details'),
            Text('$_counter'),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Increment'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _counter++;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Sub Details'),
              onPressed: () {
                context.pushRoute(SubDetailsRoute());
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@RoutePage()
class SubDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubDetailsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Sub Details'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can write in separated route screen: `/detail`, `/detail/:id`.

and in `/detail/:id` page, make two screens for desktop(split screen) and mobile(detail screen only).

Comment: or you can try [flutter_adaptive_scaffold](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_adaptive_scaffold)